# Linux Ubuntu 16.04 - Always stuck on splash screen (NMI Watchdog: Bug)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, liveusb, ubuntu-16.04

I've got a problem. I made a Live USB with Ubuntu 16.04 to install/test it. I reset my laptop and it starts from the USB with Ubuntu. Everything seems to work fine until it reaches the splash screen or loading screen:

[image]

It stops working and remains on this screen forever. I can't even press ESC to see the terminal if the screen gets stuck. I can press ESC and check the terminal before it gets stuck and this is what I'm getting:

[image]

**NMI watchdog: Bug: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s!**

This will repeat forever with an interval of about 10 seconds. It changes CPU number sometimes. Yesterday I was getting error in CPU #5. What is happening? I can't even choose what to do: install or test.

My specifications:

- Already installed Windows 7 in main SSD.
- SSD Samsung 128GB / HGST 1TB
- Intel Core i7 6700HQ 2.6GHZ (4 physical cores, 4 logical cores)
- Two USB 3.1 ports and two USB 3.0 ports. (Trying to run Ubuntu using USB)
- NVidia GTX970M 3GB

Comment: I've rarely if ever had a problem with Ubuntu Live, but occasionally an installed Ubuntu won't boot after running Windows, and I've found that powering off completely (mains and battery disconnected for at least 10 seconds) clears the problem. Otherwise, there is a possible work-round in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/726306/nmi-watchdog-on-haswell) (the answer is not really relevant to a Live CD).

Comment: @AFH I can't remove the battery, it's integrated. The question you made reference involves Ubuntu already installed (updating the kernel). I can't even get to the installation menu. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Please read my previous comment again. I said the answer was not relevant, but the work-round might be. That's why I linked to the question, not the answer.